# pandas.DataFrame.plot showing colormap inconsistently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, colormap

So am trying to make some plots and was trying to use the cmap "jet". It kept appearing as viridis, so I dug around SE and tried some very simple plots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 100)
y = x
t = x
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T

df.plot(kind="scatter", x=0, y=1, c=t, cmap="jet")
```

[image]

```
x = np.arange(0, 100.1)
y = x
t = x
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T

df.plot(kind="scatter", x=0, y=1, c=t, cmap="jet")
```

[image]

Any thoughts on what is going on here? I can tell that it has something to do with the dtype of the fields in the dataframe (added dypte="float" to the first set of code and got the same result as in the second set of code), but don't see why this would be the case.

Naturally, what I really would like is a workaround if there isn't something wrong with my code.

Comment: Yeah that's strange and the closest is that [pandas scatter plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) `c takes str, int or array-like` (while I'm not sure why `t` isn't referring to the index which yould be int again). Anyway a fix is to use matplotlib instead of the `df.plot`, I can post an answer if that helps (didn't do it now since the question was about the root cause and not about a fix).

Comment: Even `df.plot(kind="scatter", x=0, y=1, c=df.index.values.tolist(), cmap='jet')` falls back to viridis, while df.index.values.tolist() clearly is just int.

Comment: @MagnusO_O posting that as an answer would be fine. I'll edit my question so it suggests a work around is also acceptable ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually seems to be related to pandas (scatter) plot and as you've pointed out to dtype float - some more details at the end.

A **workaround** is to use matplotlib.
The plot is looking the same in the end, but the `cmap="jet"` setting is also applied for float dtype:

[image]

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 100.1)
y = x
t = x
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

sc_plot = ax.scatter(df[0], df[1], c=t, cmap="jet")
fig.colorbar(sc_plot)

ax.set_ylabel('1')
ax.set_xlabel('0')

plt.show()
```

Or the shorter version (a little bit closer to the brief df.plot call) using [pyplot instead of the Object Oriented Interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T

sc_plot = plt.scatter(df[0], df[1], c=t, cmap="jet")
plt.colorbar(sc_plot)
plt.ylabel('1')
plt.xlabel('0')
plt.show()
```

---

Concerning the root cause why pandas `df.plot` isn't following the cmap setting:

The closest I could find is that [pandas scatter plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) `c` takes

> str, int or array-like

(while I'm not sure why t isn't referring to the index which would be int again).

Even `df.plot(kind="scatter", x=0, y=1, c=df.index.values.tolist(), cmap='jet')` falls back to viridis, while `df.index.values.tolist()` clearly is just int.

Which is even more strange, as [pandas `df.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) also uses matplotlib by default:

> Uses the backend specified by the option plotting.backend. By default,
> matplotlib is used.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a new bug in pandas 1.5.0. Reverting pandas to 1.4.4 fixes it. So if you don't need 1.5.0 per se, I'd suggest to reinstall 1.4.4 until the bugfix.