# IDLE isn't plotting some colormap examples that I've searched for online to learn how to use colormaps by myself. Is IDLE the problem or is it my code

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

I tried 3 examples and none worked:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def fig1():
    
    #import data and create dataframe
    wine_url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data' 
    wine_column_headers = ['Alcohol','Malic acid','Ash','Alcalinity of ash',  
                       'Magnesium','Total phenols','Flavanoids',
                       'Nonflavanoid phenols','Proanthocyanins','Color intensity', 
                       'Hue','OD280/OD315 of diluted wines' ,'Proline']
    wine_df = pd.read_csv(wine_url, names = wine_column_headers)

    #figure
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(13, 10)

    #labels
    ax1.set_xlabel('Alcohol')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Color Intensity')
    ax1.set_title('Relationship Between Color Intensity and Alcohol Content in Wines')

    #c sequence
    c = wine_df['Color intensity']

    #plot
    plt.scatter( wine_df['Alcohol'], wine_df['Color intensity'] , c=c, 
            cmap = 'RdPu', s = wine_df['Proline']*.5, alpha =0.5)
    cbar = plt.colorbar()
    cbar.set_label('Color Intensity')
    
    print("fig1 complete")

#############################################################################

def fig2():
    x = np.arange(0, 100)
    y = x
    t = x
    df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T

    df.plot(kind="scatter", x=0, y=1, c=t, cmap="jet")

    print("fig2 complete")

#############################################################################

def fig3():
    df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 0], [7.0, 3.2, 1],
                    [6.4, 3.2, 1], [5.9, 3.0, 2]],
                   columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])
    ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='length', y='width', c='DarkBlue')
    print("fig3 complete")

fig1()
fig2()
fig3()
```

It only prints the last lines, so there is a problem with the plots. Am I missing any argument that I've overlooked?

I expected to get the same images as in other people's codes:

[pandas.DataFrame.plot showing colormap inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976600/pandas-dataframe-plot-showing-colormap-inconsistently)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIN3i.png)

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-colormaps-with-matplotlib-to-create-colorful-plots-in-python-969b5a892f0c

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7hF3.png)

I don't remember where I got fig3's code from, but I think it was in another example online.

Comment: Try adding `plt.show()` to the end of each function.

Comment: Oh my god, how did I miss that. Thank you so much for reminding me!